# Debugging ArcPy ImportToolBox AttributeError: Object: Tool or environment <ConcatenateRowValues_AA> not found?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, attributeerror

I am trying to use the ConcatenateRowValues tool provided by ESRI. My overall code for my script is working fine except when it tries to use the **ConcantenateRowValues** Tool. I start by importing the proper toolbox and then attempt to get my script to access it. Below is my code to do this:

```
arcpy.ImportToolbox("C:/Users/'USERNAME'/Desktop/BaseLayer/ConcatenateRowValue101/ConcatenateRowValues101.tbx")
arcpy.ConcatenateRowValues_AA(hlint, "SHORT_DESC", "NAME", "Hydro_Line", "-")
```

The Error that's returned is:

`Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 67, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\'USERNAME'\Desktop\BaseLayer\ConcatenateRowValue101\ConcatenateRowValues101.tbx", line 54, in ConcatenateRowValues
    /jVXV+BHwwJ5+Gfgv/wnbP8A+NV2Eo+ZTjHPQ9qlR60cIvojBSkupxw+Avwvz/yTTwX/AOE7Z/8A
AttributeError: Object: Tool or environment <ConcatenateRowValues_AA> not found`

This is a different error from when an invalid function name is called on `arcpy`:

```
>>> arcpy.ConcatenateRowValuesASDF_AA(hlint, "SHORT_DESC", "NAME", "Hydro_Line", "-")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ConcatenateRowValuesASDF_AA'
```

That means ArcPy is seeing the model but not wanting to run it. Why not? What's the reason for the `Tool or environment <ConcatenateRowValues_AA> not found` error?

Comment: I'd like to add that when using the tool as a python script after it's been exported it works perfect. This error only occurs when I put the Tool into a larger script.

Comment: [This](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/212174/8548) may or may not be related. Unfortunately for your specific case, the toolbox is already built. But I tested the toolbox you're working with, and from everything I can tell, `AA` *is* the toolbox's built in alias.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me if I explicitly specify an alias when calling `ImportToolbox`:

```
arcpy.ImportToolbox("C:/Users/'USERNAME'/Desktop/BaseLayer/ConcatenateRowValue101/ConcatenateRowValues101.tbx", "thealias")
arcpy.ConcatenateRowValues_thealias(hlint, "SHORT_DESC", "NAME", "Hydro_Line", "-")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to re-examine the properties to check the name and alias that you gave to your tool and toolbox respectively.

From the [ImportToolbox Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v0000005z000000):

> The tool is identified by the tool name and the toolbox alias

In your case:

> arcpy.ConcatenateRowValues_AA

1. Your tool should have a **name** of ConcatenateRowValues.
2. Your toolbox should have an **alias** of AA

I am assuming that where your question says `'USERNAME'` you have just post-edited that into your code and error, and are actually using a valid username.

Comment: I've double checked my syntax with the answer you've provided, everything is as it should be. The tool works outside my script but when I add it to the script I'm working on it doesn't seem to want to work.