# AttributeError: Object: Tool or environment <MyTool_mytools> not found

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox

I have the following Python toolbox in a file named `test.pyt`:

```
import arcpy

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "MyToolbox"
        self.alias = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [MyTool]


class MyTool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "MyTool"
        self.description = "Does some custom things"
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""
        return [arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="My Arg",
            name="my_arg",
            datatype="GPString",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input"
        )]

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""
        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        my_arg = parameters[0].valueAsText
        my_arg_str = u'My Arg: {}'.format(my_arg)
        arcpy.AddMessage(my_arg_str)
        print my_arg_str
        return
```

It works fine when I run it using ArcMap:

[image: Perfectly functioning run of tool in ArcMap]

But if I try to execute it using a Python script, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MyUser/Documents/ArcGIS/make_package.py", line 13, in <module>
    arcpy.MyTool_mytools(u'some value')
  File "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\ArcGIS\test.pyt", line 22, in MyTool
    """Define parameter definitions"""
AttributeError: Object: Tool or environment <MyTool_mytools> not found
```

The following script reproduces the error and shows that arcpy can find the newly imported toolbox:

```
import inspect
import os

import arcpy


pyt_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), u'test.pyt')
arcpy.ImportToolbox(pyt_path, u'mytools')

print(arcpy.MyTool_mytools)
print(inspect.getargspec(arcpy.MyTool_mytools))

arcpy.MyTool_mytools(u'some value')

print(u'SUCCESS!')
```

Its output is

```
<function MyTool at 0x0DBDC7F0>
ArgSpec(args=['my_arg'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(None,))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/ArcGIS/make_package.py", line 13, in <module>
    arcpy.MyTool_mytools(u'some value')
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\ArcGIS\test.pyt", line 22, in MyTool
    """Define parameter definitions"""
AttributeError: Object: Tool or environment <MyTool_mytools> not found
```

Note the `function` and `ArgSpec` objects. These show that the function exists on the `arcpy` module. So the failure is somewhere inside those functions.

Why does executing the tool fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that ArcGIS is funny about the alias on the toolbox. First of all, we **must** specify an alias:

```
self.alias = "mytools"
```

If you don't, you'll always get this error. Now the script runs successfully:

```
<function MyTool at 0x0E2737F0>
ArgSpec(args=['my_arg'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(None,))
My Arg: some value
SUCCESS!
```

Leaving the alias unspecified in `ImportToolbox` also works:

```
arcpy.ImportToolbox(pyt_path)
```

But there's another caveat. The alias you pass to `ImportToolbox` must be the same as the toolbox's built in alias. So this **won't** work:

```
arcpy.ImportToolbox(pyt_path, u'mytoolswithadifferentalias')
```

So I recommend just calling `ImportToolbox` without an alias argument.

Comment: Not sure who proposed that edit, but please post a separate answer if you have significant info to add. You can find the suggested edit content [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/114819). (Not sure about rep limits on that page.)

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party here but it's also worth noting that **toolbox aliases and tool names cannot contain underscores**. So, `self.alias = "my_toolbox"` will cause the same error you describe in your question, but `self.alias = "mytoolbox"` will work.

Presumably this is because of the way ArcPy uses the `arcpy.<tool_name>_<alias>()` form for accessing tools in toolboxes. More than one underscore would confuse what the `<tool_name>` is and what the `<alias>` is.